# Google Play and Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-play-console

In My Company we have an google account(Say A) linked with firebase and everything published to the store except one app is published to different account(Say B) we invited into but it's firebase linked in our account, Our account has been locked and we couldn't restore it by anyway so we created new one and i'm republishing the apps all over again , but the problem is when i create new firebase project with the app that published on account B i can't because firebase keep tells me that project is found before specially when i add the fingerprint due to notifications and other stuff i need .
so now i have to change the package name or application id of the project to update firebase , but now i can't upload new version of the app on the playstore console because of the different of package names , so can i make something to upload the app to same app on store but new version and package name or not , or how i solve this thing ?

just tried to upload same app with different package names and rejected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.